# Ways to improve the quality of questions asked by new users

Tags: discussion, new-users

Every day, there are hundreds (thousands?) of questions asked that are not fit for the Stack Overflow model and end up getting addressed in different ways such as..

- Closed as a duplicate question
- Closed and downvoted very quickly due to the lack of information
- Information that is gradually dragged out via comments until the question is answerable

Whilst, closing is a very viable way of dealing with these questions, they still add noise to the pool of questions and those that have thought out their question find themselves with less time and attention paid to their question.

This raises my question... is there anything that can be done to help new users identify what structure their question is expected to be in in order to return a positive response?

Comment: The first post review queue?

Comment: Just linking my question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260039/57475

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Before any users are *allowed* to ask their first question they are first presented with a page that tells them to read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and requires that they confirm that they have read it before posting their first question.

That's a pretty strong emphasis on this information.

People of course *don't* read the page, and they click through to the page where they can ask their question.  Many people will do this no matter how hard you try to get them to read some information before asking their question.

Comment: @Sayse This isn't a proposal.  It's how the site has worked for a very long time.  This has been in place for like a year.  That's why this post is written in the present tense.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise/ forgot about this, plus personally, I had a large break in between asking my first question and my second, so a reminder a long the way would have helped me. (Deleted my first comment since this comment will work directly to your question)

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is much more that can be done to stopping duplicate questions personally...

In a question that got asked on MetaSO from a disgruntled "new" user about downvoting (I'm not going to link to it as it wasn't constructive), the final comment from another user stuck out to me...

> People get voted down even when they are new and don't know how the stackoverflow system works yet

I was about to post a comment about how the Ask Question page has a nice little orange square that states what is expected but I realised that it doesn't really make it obvious of where to find such information (in my opinion).

[image: How to ask]

To me, this seems cluttered with emphasis and detail in the wrong places and I believe  it can be improved by updating this "How to ask" box in different ways:

1. Move it *above* the question fields. On smaller resolutions and window sizes, this orange box can be hidden from users altogether (without scrolling) and therefore completely ignored.
2. Remove the bold outlining from "Is your question about programming?" - The user already found stack overflow, for the most part I would have thought/hoped that it is a programming question. I do think it might still be a useful note but I don't think it is the first thing that should be shown in this list
3. "We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed" - Needs a rephrase, this sounds like a comment instead of a request. I suggest - "Questions should strive for a definite answer"
4. "Provide details. Share your research"  - Seems very vague and passive to me. This is where I think the text should be bold and preferably contain a link to a meta page/wiki that shows examples of valid questions
5. Include a direct link somewhere to the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page - I use the `[ask]` comment quite often as it does go very in depth into what is expected but this does seem to be a little hidden.

Comment: The first bold phrase drives the attention to read the whole box. I agree that the current phrase is not too good, as they may just think 'Yes, of course it is programming' and stop reading. I would suggest replacing it with something that alerts the new user that his question may not be answered if he isn't cautious. Example: Read this to avoid downvotes and getting your question closed.

Comment: Even better if you show there are many wrong questions around like in: 'Do this to prevent your question from being part of the XXXX of the daily new questions that are quickly downvoted or closed'

Answer (score 4):

There have been many questions on meta about how to handle bad questions, the people who ask them, and the people who answer them.

We've tried nagging the user before they enter the question. For example if you start to type a question you'll get a list that says "Hey, some of these questions might provide you with an answer."

And the offenders simply ignore it, right?

So lets not let them ignore it.  Let's make them look at and respond to the duplicate questions. Yes they will have to work harder to ask their question, but that's the point!

If a poster starts to ask a question that the system thinks is a possible duplicate, display the list of possible dupes and force the poster to respond explicitly to each one (up to a reasonable limit -- say 10).   Make them explain why the "duplicate" question does not meet their needs, and make these responses part of the permanent record for this question.

Doing this up front will have a couple of benefits.

First because they are forced to actually open the page containing the possible duplicate question and its answers they may find what they are looking for and not post the question in the first place. (It might even make sense to reward them for agreeing "Yes my question was going to be a duplicate, so I did not ask it."  Say the first couple of times they do that they get some bonus rep (not to often or this, too, will be exploited by rep-hounds.)

Second, if their question is truly addressing new ground, they will have already gone through the process of explaining why the previous questions don't address their need.  During the process they may clarify their question to the point where it's is obvious why the new question needs to be asked.

Finally, if they try to blow by this and don't provide reasonable justification it should be much easier for others to down-vote, flag, etc. their question.  No need for a dialog.  The usual "this is a duplicate", "no it's not" dialog will have already happened -- and only the OP will have to invest time in it.

In egregious cases, we could even impose a more severe penalty for questioners who don't respond appropriately to the "is this a duplicate" challenges.  Maybe significant loss of rep or quicker question bans at the discretion of moderators.

Bottom line, rather than trying to penalize bad questions after the fact, make them harder to ask in the first place.

[implementation detail:  There should be a way to view the other questions and their answers without losing track of the page on which the new question is being submitted.  Like any good "idea man" I leave that to the ingenuity of the developers (grin)]

Comment: Don't get the moderators involved at the outset, they are plenty busy enough. And as they are new, there isn't all that much to revoke. A faster question-ban if it gets closed for one of the proposed dupes now, that's reasonable. Should those proposed dupes and the answers be public? Probably, but maybe restricted to potential close-voters...

Comment: Moderators don't get involved unless someone flags the question as "this is a duplicate and the OP provided bogus answers to the "Why doesn't this previous question meet your needs" questions.

Comment: Yes. The problem is that I suspect that to be fairly common. So there has to be a way to handle that (most of the time) without mod-involvement.