# Is my question on-topic on Stack Overflow? Let's guide new users

Tags: feature-request, questions

A well designed guided process **before** asking the question would help our community and will also have a positive impact on the quality of new questions.

---

Stack Overflow slowly becomes overwhelmed by the number of new posts. Many of the new posts are of low quality or are simply off-topic for Stack Overflow. This is especially true for users first interacting with the Stack Exchange universe.

I think the right path to ensuring good quality is not to make it harder for new users to ask questions. Instead we should focus on making it as easy as possible to find out if a question will be well received here on Stack Overflow, before formulating the question itself.

I propose that `Ask Question` at the very beginning shows an interactive flowchart or decision tree that helps new users find the right Stack Exchange site for their question (if any).

Ideally the process would check first if the new question would be on-topic on Stack Overflow. If not, check if it could be on-topic on a partner site and refer to it. If it is on-topic, the goal is to assure that the user has gathered all required information required for a decent question. In case of a bug it should e.g. make sure that the user already has a MCVE and if not link to the excellent documentation we already have.

This question is not a exact duplicate of [Establish a two stage question commit process?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289144/establish-a-two-stage-question-commit-process). Adding a checkmark just before submitting the question is not what I propose. I want a guide before new users start typing their question.

Comment: This already exists in some forms and a "Wizard" has already been proposed a few times and been shot down each time because it means a lot of work for very little payoff, and is a solution that most users will just skip (when was the last time you read a program's EULA or Terms & Conditions before scrolling to the bottom to click the checkmark?).

Comment: Do you mean something like the big banner about the SE sites tour?.. As much as I'd love to find something people would actually look at, all attempts are futile as the people that should read them, are the ones that never do.

Comment: `and is a solution that most users will just skip` - I would not make it a tour, but a mandatory process to go through.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Hmh, similar idea, but not really a duplicate. I would do a process before typing a question - not just for reviewing the format, but to make sure that the content which the user intends to write about is on-topic in the first place.

Comment: @cel If you look closer, the checklist contains more than just prooving the questions format.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, oh okay, missed that. Yet I think this proposal is better. I want a wizard that helps people to find the right options right before they start putting together the final question. Having the dialog after having composed the question appears to be wrong timing. If the notification about off-topicness is after having composed the question, the user is confronted with two equally bad options: 1) Submitting nevertheless 2) Abandon the question and accept that they wasted a lot of their time.

Comment: Relevant [answer by Servy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256677/1324033) on a similar question I asked

Comment: @Sayse, I don't think this is the right way to think about the problem. Before we install a software we are presented the terms of service and we are explicitly asked to agree. The point is not that the information is missing, but that people come here to solve a problem, not to read about how they can use the site. Our goal should be to present the way the site is to be used in a very simple way and not blame users for not reading the docs.

Comment: So... ..  the docs are redundant and we should get rid of them completely?

Comment: @MartinJames, obviously not. But assuming that most people read them, seems as naive as assuming that people actually read the EULA. Of course you should read it... :)

Comment: 'people come here to solve a problem', yes.  If only they came here to positively contribute to the site instead of trying to squeeze out the last drops of O-negative:(

Comment: @cel most users will just post anything in the wizard to get their question on the site. People who don't need it will use it, and people who do need it will misuse it :/

Comment: @Patrice, could be, but that'd imply that all of the poor content question come from people who would cheat the system to intentionally post those bad questions to stackoverflow. I really think that most people who ask for tool recommendations e.g. don't do it on purpose, but simply because they didn't read what's on topic. Same goes for math questions.

Comment: @cel 100% with you about maliciousness (i think most off topic questions are just misguided users) but what makes you believe they will read THAT wizard instead of the current one? If they don't go to the help center which is offered, they are just as likely to not read whatever is in your wizard and just post anyway, no?

Comment: @Patrice, In my opinion it's a huge difference. It'd basically be like comparing a survey with an article. The user does not have to read a page of text, instead answers simple survey questions. So basically something like `Please select what of these 5 options describes your question best` a), b), c), d), e). And depending on the answer the system asks a more specific question or refers to a partner site. In the end users have to answer maybe 3 questions instead of reading a page of text.

Comment: Putting 'If you are posting code/data that has a problem, you MUST clearly describe the debugging steps you have already taken and results so obtained' at the top will take out 99% of posts.

Comment: @cel and what will stop people from clicking: a, a,a,a, till they get to "ask a question" page? (genuinely curious. I would love for a succesful wizard for new questions to be implemented. I just see it as an endeavor too complicated to be done properly)

Comment: @Patrice, there's no way to prevent that. But that's not my goal anyway. It does not have to be fool-proof. - it just has to be reduce the number of bad questions. I'd argue even a very simple wizard will do this.

Comment: @cel then.... Maybe I've grown too cynical, but I've seen enough of "screw off,just give me my answer"and "i don't care for your quality, jut get me out of my jam NOW" to think this'll impact much. That said,might still be worth a try

Comment: @Patrice: What might stop users from clicking A, A, A would be capturing the answers and making lying on the flowchart grounds for immediate closure.  Also, making sure that the answer that allows you to proceed is not always the first one.  "Are you writing code?  No."  "Is your question about a development tool?  Yes."  "Can this tool be used for things other than writing code?  No." -> asks [question about ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74228630/cant-start-openssh-server-service-sshd-error-1067) -> closed for lying that the tool can't be used by non-programmers.