# Have it show in search results if a question is a user's first post in SE network

Tags: feature-request, search, new-users

New users can have some trouble using SO: formatting, sentence structure, including MREs, research effort, etc. If you are an experienced SE user, you (most likely) want to be able to help these users. But, you also most likely don't have infinite time.

If it displayed an indicator of some sort to who is new to the SE Network, editors would be able to check them first (especially if they don't have the First Posts review queue unlocked), and general interacters could help show these users how the site works and how to operate it.

TECHNICAL NOTE: I mean if it is their first post *anywhere* on SE, not just one one particular site, excluding Meta, as it works quite differently.

It could look something like this, for example:

[image]

*Sorry for bad art, not a graphic designer*

Comment: What about new user notice below user flair?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of indications that take the user as source. For that same reason I hate the "new contributor" label. What I could support is some kind of simple quality indicator of the content. I can imagine an "IP" tag, meaning "Improvement Possible" and that is shown for posts that when analyzed via a Bayesian algorithm turn out to be a formatting mess. (so we feed the model wit known good and known bad examples).

Comment: I am pretty sure your proposal will achieve the opposite effect, and new users will start gaining *less* attention: any moderately active answerer/editor notices pretty shortly that badly formatted, unclear, opinionated, or broad questions come mostly from new users, so a prominent marker essentially telling them "this is likely to be a bad question" will only serve as a deterrent.

Comment: What would happen if the user delete all the posts, and post a new one, effectively making it the "first" post again?

Comment: It took me about a week to become blind to the "new contributor" moniker so I don't see the benefit of further highlighting that a question is probably bad. I open a question and I interact based on the question's merit. It doesn't matter if the person is new or has 20k rep, a shite question is a shite question. I'm probably more critical of established users asking a shite question to be honest.

Comment: @AndrewT. wait ... are you suggesting that users will be gaming the system? Please provide evidence this has ever happened before on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @rene nah... I'm poking fun at how [the current "new contributor" label works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314476/241919) :p

Comment: @AndrewT. That's for the development team to figure out. If it was miraculously decided that this moniker is a good idea whatsoever then I think https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/ is good enough reason to not try gambling the system.

Comment: You might not know it yet but you're essentially asking this: [Ways to improve the quality of questions asked by new users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256675/ways-to-improve-the-quality-of-questions-asked-by-new-users)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## First and foremost

There is already a ["First Posts"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) review queue; at 500 rep you gain access to this so by all means please participate!

[image]

### Secondly

If you're interested in a user's first ever post then check out their profile and look at the oldest post. Just because you're interested doesn't mean I should forever see "First Post" monikers everywhere; the single reputation point is usually enough of a giveaway.

If you're interested in StackExchange-wide stats then check out https://stackexchange.com/users/2521234/monkeyzeus?tab=top. I for one have never even looked at that screen until today. Maybe **you** can request a feature to see it organized by date instead of votes; whatever.

### Thirdly

> TECHNICAL NOTE: I mean if it is their first post anywhere on SE, not just one one particular site, excluding Meta, as it works quite differently.

WHY??

I am well versed in Stack Overflow and a number of other sites but I would presumably ask a terrible first question on [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/), [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/), and countless other sites.

What good is it to know that my first ever question was on any of those particular sites?

Each site has it's own "First Posts" review queue for good reason.

Answer (score 5):

A feature like this exists: reputation. Use filters on the [question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) to find the questions that you’re best able to help with and scan for posts by users with low rep.

For the vast majority of users, having a reputation less than 101 means they’re not active on other sites (reaching 200 rep on any site grants the association bonus of 100 rep). Having 1 or so reputation means that they probably haven’t done anything noteworthy on this site yet (many, if not most, 1 rep users are posting for the first time). It’s not a completely accurate system, but it works pretty well.

Search isn’t the place where I would want to see this info, and it would even be distracting because that’s not what I’m looking for when I search.