# Is SO suffering from its own success?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question that didn't receive an answer.  No drama, but I was curious because once upon a time (I have been a member for almost 11 years) people were rep hungry and questions would be answered really quickly.

What I found was quite surprising...questions in [the review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review) simply aren't being dealt with and I suspect that it is because of the sheer volume of questions; 4.8k first posts!

[image]

Pretty much every other SE community I am in has an empty review queue, but in the case of SO, it looks like it will *never* be cleared.

I know that I am part of the solution, I could contribute, but I do a lot in other communities.

I suspect that the overall quality of SO questions and answers is suffering due to its own success.

Are there any plans to address this issue?

Comment: Note that one will almost certainly not receive an answer just because a post doesn't get through First Posts - that's not a queue for SMEs answering. The problem stems from the sheer number of questions (and their quality causing a low signal to noise ratio). See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285903 It's not completely unfixable to optimize for pearls instead, but it's not an easy problem, and the motivation by those with the power to implement such a thing is lacking too

Comment: @CertainPerformance I do realise that answers aren't based on the First Post queue, but the size of that queue is indicative of the backlog in the review queue and hence a possible diminishing of post quality.

Comment: *"... and the motivation by those with the power to implement such a thing is lacking too."* - because advertising revenue is not directly related to the quality of questions and answers ... or even the probability that any given question will be answered.

Comment: Related: *[What can be done about the massive Close Votes queue on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183840)*, *[Huge close votes review queue on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151833/)*, and *[26,000 questions have close votes, now what?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111734/)*.

Comment: The garbage-to-legitimate-question (that are not homework or duplicate) ratio has sky-rocketed. Finding the worth-answering questions is much more of a hit-or-miss / needle-in-a-haystack than it was even 5 years ago. This doesn't really have anything to do with the queues, it's just a fact. And in high traffic tags (eg html) you _still_ have people wasting time answering the garbage questions instead of close/down-voting. The decrease in the downvote rep penalty for the recipient probably is making this worse.

Comment: You wanna know a super fast way to reduce the number of first posts in the review queue? Hammer all of the duplicate questions as quickly as possible.  This way unknowing new users won't waste time writing answers to low-hanging fruit. New users are also posting redundant answers on old pages -- for these downvote the new answer, leave a comment, and vote to delete.  We also need a mechanism to stop the new users from developing FGITW tendancies -- oh, I've got an idea https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397526/2943403

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question but I don't see a solid link between "no answer" and "dealing with review queues". To me it's two different things.

Comment: "...the overall quality of SO questions and answers is suffering due to its own success" I don't understand that part of the question. Could you elaborate more on that. How exactly did the success of SO in the past reduce quality of questions and answers? The two things could also be just coincidence.

Comment: The large number of reviews in the reopen queue compared to the close vote review queue isn't good. That was better in the past. It means that reopen as a way of correcting mistakes may not work currently.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas when did that decrease in downvote rep penalty change? I didn't get that memo.

Comment: *I could contribute* ... so, why don't you here on SO? I'm asking because your reasoning might contain the argument why many others also decide to not review and to not moderate. The lack of reviewers always has been an issue.

Comment: @4386427 it has no direct correlation, that was by way of introduction.  But I do wonder if were some of the questions asked since mine weeded out for whatever reason, mine might have had stayed visible for longer and then received an answer.  Or it might have been deleted...either would be fine.

Comment: @Steve Sorry but I'm still confused. It's unclear to me whether you ask about "number of unanswered questions" or "number of posts under review".

Comment: @rene because I am happy to make a contribution to a community where I feel it will make a difference.  I have helped on the review queue at SO in the past.  Now, it feels pointless.  Me handling 10 questions won't make a difference.  And SE doesn't pay me enough to spend all day doing that.  However, before you throw it back at me, go check my rep and stats at Webmasters.  I am one of the top reviewer queue slashers, participating daily.

Comment: @4386427 I think the high number of both is connected.  And let me make it clear, this isn't a whinge about my question not being answered.

Comment: Those 10 would make a difference if the 10,000 other reviewers would also do 10. I feel like we keep spiraling down this way and in  6 to 8 weeks you can write another meta post how SO has had even more success suffering. If you can't do 10, do 1 each day should be a encouraging message to latent reviewers

Comment: Is there a way we could see some tag-statistics on those "first posts". This might give us some insight on how to tackle this queue.

Comment: "Are there any plans to address this issue?" - what issue exactly? The issue that people don't search enough for their answers? The product of our success is that we have a knowledge base which is *filled* and asking a question has become something you should only rarely need to do. Let me rephrase that: asking a question *on stack overflow* is something that you should now rarely have to do.

Comment: I find it frustrating that I am supposed to turn everyone away who asked a bad question instead of taking a shot and just trying to help. I believe we live in a bubble. I can go look at 15 year old forum posts of myself and my questions were TERRIBLE. Yet, *there* I got help.

Comment: @Zyl there is nothing wrong with editing a question into shape and answering it. But we prefer to be a Q and A site, not *Take a Guess* forum. Nothing forbids users to post elsewhere if the Q/A model isn't a good fit. But expecting that the Q/A model should host anything in all shapes and forms is a bit too much to handle.

Comment: @Zyl I find it frustrating that I am supposed to ignore people who asked a good question because they are drowned by shotgun Q&A. I believe we live in a bubble. I can go look at year old [so] posts of myself and my questions were TERRIBLE. Yet, there I got sorted out so the good questions that actually helped me later on got the spotlight.

Comment: @Zyl Then why not use those forums, and accept that this site has different operating principles? Is it so hard to tolerate that some people do things differently, and just let them be?

Comment: Let's see how long this lasts on the "Hot Meta Posts" page before it's removed/hidden.

Comment: 5 years ago people were asking the same thing, I'm pretty sure it was getting asked 10 years ago... how many meta topics is it going to take for SE to do something? IMO SE at this point should just embrace the perception and let users ask simple questions into some kind of "helpdesk" frontend and have people link to the question they're looking for and maybe it only gets promoted to the "real archive" if it's not found to be a dupe. Sadly no matter how good of a reference you make, there's still going to be people who want personalized 1 on 1 help, which is at odds with SE's 'reference' roots.

Comment: Don't underestimate the effect of SO's more recent veer off the cliff of social "justice." It wasn't very kind to the people who would bother with moderation activities.

Comment: There's several reasons. Lots of people lost the will the help out with volunteer duties after the firing mods/pronouns debacle two years ago. Also, ten or so moderators quit  SO then and the site has never really recovered. In addition, there's been a longterm focus on quantity over quality by the company, which ultimately leads to longer review queues since the new user/veteran user ratio is far from balanced nowadays - there simply aren't enough people do the reviews, even if they are willing.

Comment: Personally, I'm happy to help out with reviews when I get paid for it. I'm not going to do volunteer moderator duty to a greedy private company when there's non-profit open source competitors who are also in need of more mods.

Comment: I'm not sure where to leave this feedback: because this post has three-digit vote score (104 when I write this), the appearance of this post and its score on Hot Meta Posts is ... awkward. There is very little space between the score and title, i.e. "104Is SO ... "

Comment: `I suspect that the overall quality of SO questions and answers is suffering due to its own success.` I have the same feeling lately. Even though i am not a terrorist of the perfect question. (well i hope i am not)

Comment: I've totally misunderstood the point of the triage queue for years, and looking into them as part of my response to a different question has me wondering what use they are at all. Triage LOOKS like the right place to hold weak questions until they are improved, but that's not what happens. Bad questions are pushed through, downvoted, closed and deleted before the triage process even gets started.

Comment: Worse, there's no way, or none that I could easily find, to filter to my areas of expertise and interests. This dooms questions, good and bad alike, to be triaged by folks who likely don't understand the question.

Comment: So what is the point of Tirage? Preventing the truly bad questions from reaching the front page?

Comment: Aren't those figures near an all-time low?

Comment: @rene "why don't you (contribute) on SO".  As I mentioned, I do on other communities, since this question still seems to have a lot of traction, out of curiosity I just had a look.  In Webmasters, my primary hangout, I have asked only 4 questions.  But I have answered 335, edited 155 posts , raised 365 helpful flags, cast 346 votes.  I reckon I am doing my share overall.

Comment: @Steve I had seen that when I left my first comment and that is appreciated. I'm not blaming you for not doing reviews here. I'm honestly curious what (de)motivates curators. I don't want to miss a chance when we find a common issue that turns out to be fixable, be it guidance, joined effort or a feature request for tooling.

Comment: Not anything that hasn't already been said, but, prompted by this post I just had another stab at reviewing. A few years ago, I quite enjoyed reviewing as a way to randomly stumble across interesting questions that I'd otherwise have overlooked, and which occasionally I could even offer an answer for. The 5 minutes I've just spent in Triage has left me utterly despondent, depressed and downright terrified for the future of the software development industry, and the world at large.

Comment: Some excellent questions don't get an answer because no-one knows the answer.

Comment: There are not just plans to address this, it's already in progress: Requesting to close questions of 11k rep users within an hour (and later actually closing it) since it's not 100 % perfect from the beginning on: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68704174/1744774. </sarc>.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave well, of all options you had Triage is the worst one to pick but it is competing with the H&I queue ...

Comment: I don't think SO is necessarily suffering from it's success, *though it's users certainly are.*

Comment: @KevinB [It's **SE** which doesn't necessarily suffer](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service).

Comment: I used to really like editing rubbish questions but the cap on vanity points has stopped me checking the queues. I will edit one when I come across it just browsing the site to answer questions but never check the queues any more.

Comment: Finally a good question on meta, most of them are just people whining about why their flag got rejected, or questions that get shit on by the meta elite

Comment: @SethSpearman respect is mutual and unfortunately, a lot of "newbies" (as you put it) don't formulate clearly defined answerable questions. I'm not saying that is you personally just an observation from someone who has tried to answer questions on [so] for years. It's not about being "Nazis" it's about caring about the community and the quality of content for others which is often lost on people who just want a quick hit "Fix my problem!".

Comment: It doesnt matter what you do in other communities or if you help here or not. You don't need to justify yourself. It always looks strange for me when people say something like. Similar to "I wont give that beggar a dollar, I am donating already to charity each month" or something like this. What do you want me to say? "good boy" ?

Comment: When I see a question sit there and has not answers after 10 minutes it is 99% of the time a bad question which no one understands or has way too much content to comprehend. Or it was tagged in a way that no one sees it.

Comment: @user692942 I understand your perspective.  I don't want to imply that there is no such thing as a bad question.  My experience for being "rebuked" by the community for asking questions that I thought were well-formulated is mostly what I am referring to here.

Comment: Another thing maybe worth mentioning, SE knows that they (via their UI) are funneling new users to ask a question "right now", every page as a logged out user has the Ask Question button on it. That's what they are pushing for (not search). It's like somebody is whispering in their ears "This question doesn't help? Ask your own!", "Don't see your question on the front page? Ask your own!". Whereas what it should be saying is "Keep reading, the content you want is probably here somewhere."

Answer (score 184, accepted):

> Are there any plans to address this issue?

I don't think we are likely to get a direct answer to that from the people who could address it.

And I'm not sure that there would be an acceptable answer.

And I'm not even sure that the powers that be even recognize it as an issue that needs to be solved.

(I assume that most of Stack Exchange's revenue comes from adverts displayed on peoples' browsers when they land on Stack Overflow Q&A pages.  Most revenue comes from those pages that are ranked highly in search results; i.e. those with lots of upvotes.  The poor Q&A's don't get search hits ... and we wouldn't want them to.  But that means that they have no impact one way or another on revenue.)

---

And the flipside is that the deluge of (poor) questions results in poor answers because:

- the people who are good at answering get fed up and leave,
- the high rep users who remain get very selective on what they answer<sup>1</sup>
- low rep people find it difficult to get rep because people tend not to upvote an answer to a poor question ... and they don't stick around long enough to get better at writing good answers.

---

What is the answer?

I have no idea!

There are some fundamental flaws in the Stack Overflow model.  These include:

- The "split personality" of Stack Overflow as repository of knowledge versus Stack Overflow as a source of help.
- The mistaken idea that you can run a 24/7 free "help desk" for programmers using volunteer effort who are perpetually happy, patient and "welcoming".
- The mistaken idea that you can modify the behavior of new users who have no interest in anything but solving their own problems.

---

<sup>1 - It is easier to curate than to answer ...</sup>

Comment: And this answer from someone who posted  >14k answers on SO. The outlook of SO really must be quite dire. On the other hand I'm not sure how that bad current state is linked to past success? Weren't there always low quality questions posted? Did we run out of good questions in the meantime? This answer would also be equally valid in 2015, but I wonder if things have changed since then, or if it's basically still the same situation.

Comment: @Trilarion "Weren't there always low quality questions posted?" Maybe not as many as there are today. They used to be downvoted and closed more quickly, often after receiving critical comments. The new imperative to be particularly welcoming towards new users effectively promotes poorly stated questions or lowers the inhibition threshold of posting them. It encourages a feeling of entitlement to obtain detailed answers from experts (which they won't get because of the question's low quality). At the same time, it discourages expert users from pointing out that the question is not suitable.

Comment: The problem for me personally is that both the quality of approved questions have dropped a lot, and also people not caring about your answers. I don't know what the solution will be but at this rate SO is doomed to die in a few years and it's sad.

Comment: @Trilarion I think we ran out of volunteers who care and know how to curate. "The powers" made quite a good job last few years with insulting and alienating them. I, for instance, don't care anymore. I just lurk meta but I'm not sure what should happen to make me care again.

Comment: Too many users don't even care about their questions, never mind the answer, (as long as they get one).  They copy/paste in their assignment, hope that some naive nerd does all the work and then, if an answer appears, copy/paste it out and hand it in for marking.  Understanding the question/answer is an irrelevance, the only thing of importance is conning some mark into getting them a pass with the minimum effort by the OP.

Comment: (I'm not sure that "curate" was the correct word for what I was thinking.  Maybe "moderate" is closer to the mark.  We don't really have the tools that we need to properly curate the existing pile of Q&As into a decent, well-organized, well-written knowledge base.)

Comment: @Trilarion long ago, SO had a close reason that basically said "OP is missing the basic knowledge we require for participation". It was extensively used to close LQ questions like "halp I has nullpointer" or similar Qs where OP shows they don't know how to read exception messages or perform basic debugging. IIRC there's been three close reason reworks since then, and they get more useless every time, and garbage questions get closed slower while gathering more upvotes and answers. Personally, I used to use all close votes daily, but stopped when SO started chasing vistor numbers over quality.

Comment: Re *"The poor Q&A's don't get search hits"*: How does that work (not a rhetorical question)? Are specific questions hidden from the search engines (other than deletion)? The average search result (used for real research) usually returns only low-quality questions and seldomly high voted or canonical questions.

Comment: @PeterMortensen regarding search results, I tend to see the opposite - I use Google for canonical dupe-finding all the time (hey SE folks: improve search!). Yes, there are lower-rated results underneath, but I can usually find what I'm looking for without too much effort. The problem is that a ton of new users don't even go to that effort...

Comment: I feel like the first bullet point leads to all the issues outlined in the remaining ones. There is a concept that helping and building are mutually exclusive, as if we were building a perfectly load balanced bridge and no beam or material can be out of place; this simply is not analogous here, there needs be no "balance", we can both help and build. The further the belief that there is a balance between the two perpetuates, and the further that the zeal of building perfection progresses, the worse off the community will be.

Comment: @TravisJ - I don't think that the two things (knowledge base and help desk) are mutually exclusive.  However, I >do< think that it is unrealistic to expect a broad spectrum help desk to work at this scale ... if you don't properly reward the people who you expect to provide the help.

Comment: Anyway ... how do >you< propose that Stack Exchange should recruit hundreds / thousands more cheerful, knowledgable (unpaid) help-desk-style question answerers for StackOverflow?

Comment: "The 'split personality' of Stack Overflow as repository of knowledge versus Stack Overflow as a source of help" —The longer I'm here, the more I struggle with balancing these.

Comment: @PeterMortensen fun fact: google uses spelling and grammar errors as indicators of low quality content, reducing the page rank of the offending page and thereby dropping it lower in the search results. Which means that every time you edit a bad question to fix these issues, you're actively making the internet worse.

Comment: @l4mpi do you have a source for that? Making an algorithm to do that sounds like a ton of work (mostly the 'grammar' part, but I'm not sure how it would tell the difference between spelling errors and code snippets or something).

Comment: @jrh there's a lot of anecdotal evidence for the claim... googling it, I found [this page](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/googles-mueller-on-ranking-impact-of-poor-html-spelling-and-grammar/410461/) with statements from a google employee - it's not a clear "yes we penalize for bad spelling" and more a "if you don't spell stuff correctly we can't figure out what your site is about". The site also has statements from the same guy saying auto-translated content would be seen as "lower quality" [here](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/using-google-translate-to-autogenerate-content/409042/)

Comment: @jrh There was a guy a long time ago who invented the first spell-check dictionary that worked in MS Word at least a couple decades ago now. This technology has exited for at least 20 years, and it's not farfetched for an organization with the heuristics such as Google to come up with a scheme.

Comment: @searchengine27 true, but I always have a 'break in' period with Office where I have to reassure it that my coding terms aren't misspelled. Add in multiple languages, proper names, abbreviations, slang, obscure terms, changing grammar rules, etc. and it seems like it'd be easy to make a 'sometimes ok' solution but pretty hard to make a 'great' solution. Though maybe a noisy solution is OK in this case.

Comment: @jrh I imagine it will not apply the rule to proper code blocks or inline code. Which would mean that bad formatting is also an indicator of low quality. That would not exactly be entirely wrong.

Comment: `new users who have no interest in anything but solving their own problems.` If only...most of them want **someone else** to solve their problem, and they sure as hell don't care about understanding whatever that solution ends up being, as long as it's copypasta compatible.  SO used to attract users that were interested in actually learning.  The flood of zombie vampires lately, however, just suck all of the joy out of helping someone out.  What used to be a teaching/learning experience now feels more like being hounded for change at the bus stop.

Comment: @CrazyChucky: The longer I'm here, the more I *only* care about building a repository of knowledge and high-quality Q&As.  The flood of very low quality questions makes me care even less about answering them well, when they're not interesting or new.  Although I guess I'm naturally helpful enough to leave comments or try to find a useful duplicate, but if a big pointer in the right direction isn't enough for someone, I'm not usually interested in hand-holding them unless they show some sign of learning. When I started on SO, I naively wanted to answer all the unanswered [assembly] questions :P

Comment: (Actually, I think J...'s comment right above mine really put a finger on the real problem that's turned me off wanting to help individual people more often.  It seems fewer people are even interested in learning, and will keep replying asking for explicit confirmation of their specifics after you explain the general case, sometimes even in cases where they could have tried code themselves, not just conceptual questions.)  Just to be clear, there are still some good questions, and it does feel rewarding to have helped someone in the process of answering one, esp. when they grok the concept.

Comment: re: "how do >you< propose..." I don't really need to propose a solution to this, because it already existed and a lot of us have seen it work here. There is no need to force people to be nice about being a help desk. We need to change the mantra of only allowing held desk bullshit to be on topic. You get hundreds, thousands, millions, of developers in one place by offering them the opportunity to coordinate solving interesting problems. Questions are supposed to be about asking for help solving a problem, which may not be clearly defined all the time. We need to change our close culture.

Comment: @TravisJ Wrong.  Questions, like answers, are about presenting a problem that has at least some level of focus, quality, and longevity that will have future use as a reference for other readers.  That askers get answers to their questions is an **incidental** benefit to the asker, it is absolutely *not* the purpose of StackOverflow to provide tailored personal assistance for arbitrarily ill-defined problems or hopeless tangles of poorly conceived code.  Askers are as much contributors as answerers, and poor quality contributions are not useful for SO to accrue and archive indefinitely.

Comment: @J... - "An incidental benefit"... yeah,  if we took your approach, this would have failed from day #1, and that outlook you so eagerly parrot is the reason why question quality is in a state of degradation. The pedantic, hard line, over zealous crap enforcement with the idea that you can predict quality directly leads to experts not wanting to give a rubber duck about your guesswork. Some of the most famous questions here are ones which were arbitrarily ill-defined problems, because it turns out that a whole heck of a lot of people all have the same misunderstandings from time to time.

Comment: Askers are a quintessential facet of the exchange, but their purpose here is to solve a problem they encounter. Sometimes, often, that problem is a foreseen issue in the future. Placing the barrier that they must define both the circumstance of the problem and an example of its use removes the ability to theorize about direction. Most good developers are looking several steps ahead, so when you remove that group, you are left with the cruft of those who encounter problems when they get hit with them. Literally creating the environment here of helpdesk that you then run around decrying.

Comment: @TravisJ - I am not "decrying" the need for helpdesks.  Please pay attention.  I am saying that Stack Overflow is not the right way to provide a helpdesk.  It doesn't work.  As illustrated by the ratio of questions that receive no answers / no responses, and many other objective measures.  A decent IT helpdesk would never do that.  (Trust me.  I work on one!)

Comment: @TravisJ Perhaps you can clarify what you see as helpdesk questions? For me they are the countless Q&A I see in the Python tag, where people with a minuscule programming background have cargoculted an entire web/ml/automation/... task. The solution has at best only minuscule overlap with what was presented as the problem; the chance that someone needing the same solution will formulate their problem in a way to hit the question, be able to identify it as matching, and finally apply the answers tailored to the specific unrelated setup... seem slim.

Comment: @StephenC - Sorry for any confusion, that was a continuation of the previous comment to J..., I realize the system auto directs comments to answers so you must have seen it in your inbox, but in no way was that meant for you or your response here. I like your boxing of the issues, but as previously stated, there is a close culture here which is counter productive to progressing on any of the problems you highlight. It has been said many times, that the issues we face here as just as rooted in the community as in the tooling or software itself.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - Yes, exactly. Well put. No one wants to deal with that. However, with the current definition of what is "on topic", and the ridiculous zeal with which that definition is enforced by users like J..., those types of questions are actually encouraged. They are well defined, have a clear problem, have code showing the problem, and a really big set of two hands asking for a custom tailored solution. The problem there, with help desking or whatever the term de jour is, is that we are giving out fish instead of teaching people to fish.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi cont'd... Teaching is often rooted in theory, which seems to be outlawed nowadays. If someone asks a question theorizing a situation based on their solution where they know they could end up, it gets shut down.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi cont'd... Atwood said it best when mocking our current approach, "you can't have a too broad without a too narrow", and now all we get is too narrow. Turns out too broad was the good stuff, and its gone now, and a whole culture of making sure it stays gone has taken its place while somehow still being upset about narrow defined posts as well. There is a reason that so many high profile people have walked from this exchange, and it isn't because of the wild success.

Comment: @TravisJ It sounds like you're misconstruing my position.  I am 100% on board with teaching how to fish and not simply handing out fish.  I draw the line on too-broad where OP is out of their depth and their code has too many problems to solve with a single answer.  I draw the line on too narrow where OP's question is readily resolved with answers that already exist and address their problem but where, again, they are out of their depth and are incapable of seeing how the general answer *also* addresses their specific case.  These days, the latter I mostly vote to close as dupes.

Comment: @TravisJ I [wrote on this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191140/222049) many years ago (when meta was meta for all...)

Comment: @J... To reiterate the issue that the exchange faces, the closure paths here are broken; no one can ask prior to getting into the position where they have too many problems to solve or where they simply wade into a problem that everyone else faced. This whole platform was absolutely designed to give directed, targeted solutions, and the side effect was to build the repository. It would seem too many here have forgotten that this was about helping developers share solutions to problems; problems that they faced as individuals. Everyone who does remember has probably cashed out.

Answer (score 209):

Oh you sweet, sweet summer child.

In the eyes of its investors, Stack Overflow is not suffering at all. Metrics are up all across the board! More questions, more page views, more ad impressions! It's great!

Except those metrics don't actually measure the site's success, they measure how much money it's making. Which has nothing to do with the site's claimed goal [as stated in the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour):

> build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming

The metrics for *that* are the ones you've encountered. Metrics that unequivocally prove that the site is failing at that goal, and has been for **years**.

The reason is simple: quality implies moderation and curation. Stack Overflow has long been seen as hostile to new users precisely because of that insistence on quality. If new users are being turned away for whatever reason, that's page views the investors aren't getting. That's money the investors aren't getting! **The humanity!**

Thus it should be simple to understand why Stack Overflow is, in actuality, failing under the load of garbage so-called "questions" that are posted by users without a basic knowledge of the subject matter and who have zero willingness to learn. Stack Overflow's difference was *never* its Q&A format, but its insistence on a certain bar to entry, and that bar has consistently been lowered - and will continue to be in order to please investors - until something gives. I suspect it will be the moderators, but who knows.

Until that day happens, the investors - aided and abetted by Stack Exchange Inc. - will happily continue to bleed the Stack Overflow golden goose via a thousand cuts to quality, and *nothing will be changed for the better* in terms of the metrics that actually matter.

Comment: Couldn't agree more ....

Comment: "build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming" why quality about the programming question/answer isn't mentioned there?

Comment: Yeah.  Eventually, the skilled and experienced developers realize that they are not so much providing volunteer help to assist other devs - they are instead spending too much effort into volunteering free money to shareholders:(

Comment: @MartinJames That, and I've found that the number of askers willing to engage with you after posting a question seems to have diminished too. It's not uncommon to post an answer and get no feedback, no comments, no thanks, nothing. I know thanking seems to be somewhat discouraged here, but when growing up it was instilled in me to thank people for helping me as a sign of politeness and respect. When people repeatedly can't take the time to even acknowledge my effort/time, why should I continue? As an answerer, SO seems to have regressed massively over the last few years.

Comment: (And yes, I know some of that is down to different cultures. That doesn't change my perception.)

Comment: @JohnH The irony is that the questions that contain the most "please"s are also the least likely to actually act to thank you if you answer them. That's not a culture thing, that's being a s****y-human-being thing.

Comment: You're right about that.

Comment: *"barely literate Neanderthals who have zero willingness to learn"* - Can we please stop alluding to the possibility that the movie Idiocracy is becoming a reality? It scares my chickens.

Comment: Agreed. Except I don't see garbage questions as a great problem. We have the tooling for dealing with them, fortunately. To me, those who eagerly answer such questions are the greatest problem with StackOverflow. Those blinded with constant irrational hunger for imaginary internet points will be the bane of this forum, not *Neanderthals*.

Comment: "the load of garbage so-called "questions" that are posted by barely literate Neanderthals who have zero willingness to learn" - hey, that's offensive towards Neanderthals, they displayed intelligent behaviour and social morals, something which cannot be said of the average SO OP ;) But in all seriousness, I agree fully with this answer. SO started with a good idea but has gone down the drain as the original vision of a high quality knowledge repository was diluted more and more in the name of profit and being "welcoming" (towards people who couldn't care less about you).

Comment: *"...until something gives."* I doubt it. Remember [the mess of 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/138661)? There were mass mod resignations, spin-offs and whatnot. And now, two years later? SO is still the single best Q&A programming resource around. Maybe the SO system is extremely resilient, or all the alternatives are so bad, or both... I don't know, I'm just a humble developer, not a business strategist.

Comment: @oguzismail Rep whores can only exist when there are garbage questions for them to whore rep off of. Back before "be nice", there were mostly only good questions, and the rep whores either couldn't answer those, or their answers would be flushed to the bottom of the pile.

Comment: @Heinzi Eventually something will give. I agree with you that it will take a lot more abuse than what's currently going on, but it will happen. After all, it took the Roman Empire hundreds of years of decline to reach the point where the barbarians could take it, but that point was indeed reached.

Comment: @Gimby *Idiocracy* has been a reality since 2016.

Comment: Nothing will give, though, in the eyes of the investors. New users will continue strolling in, asking their questions, and generating ad revenue, long after the moderators and curators are gone. And they may get crap answers by people wanting internet points. But even after that, they will see others once got good answers there, and like Pavlov's dogs, continue asking questions even though the good answers are long gone. And it will be glorious, no whining curators or moderators, no need for CMs, no need for updates to the platform, just free ad money

Comment: *"It's got what plants crave!"*
Gamification via rep only works so long as you have something to gain from rep (i.e. enable features you care about such as editing comments or whatnot). Once usres hit a certain point it stops working if the core experience isn't rewarding in its own right. and constant low quality questions reduce that. Such questions deserve to be closed. They can be closed nicely, but they still deserve to be closed and closed with a minimum of effort.

Comment: Re *"Metrics are up all across the board!"*: You could add account signups. That was directly mentioned in the 2021-08-02 blog post *[Communities are a catalyst for technology development](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/02/q3-2021-ceo-blog-post-communities-catalyst/)* (my emphasis): *"Q2 was a time of strong growth for our public platform. We saw* ***more new accounts being created than ever***, *with April, May, and June trending at or above our highest levels from last year."*

Comment: @Toby The existence of accounts in excess of 25k rep (which is currently the maximum required to access all features), who are known rep whores, torpedoes your claim. There was one with over a million rep fairly recently. Sadly, some people will do anything for imaginary Internet points.

Comment: SO has been "collapsing" for ages. And never actually collapsed. So far, the investors have been proven right by reality, and you can't argue with reality. P.S. compensate Monica

Comment: I like how you pinpointed the issue along with a solution: just edit the tour to change the claimed goals!

Comment: @JohnH As someone that would prefer to say thanks when I receive and answer (especially if the answer is so good it doesn't require any elucidation), I am put off by the hint in the comment box being "avoid comments like '+1' or 'thanks'"

Comment: @JoshuaW That's what I meant by "I know thanking seems to be somewhat discouraged here". It's been a policy for a long time now. It's never been a policy I've agreed with and, for what little it's worth, I ignore it. If I feel the need to say thanks to someone, I will. If someone wants to come and delete that comment later on, that's up to them, but the person I was thanking would most likely have read it by then.

Comment: The moderators already "gave" during the firing moderators crisis almost 2 years ago and never recovered. I don't remember how many who quit but it was around 10 or so. Anyway, there's no point of ranting about evil private companies, it is what it is. Simply join a non-profit open source alternative if you can't stand private companies: Codidact has been up and running for a year by now.

Comment: This is the same problem many companies had in 2008 before the US stock market took a giant dump in 2009. Everything from Social Media to Q&As, are currently being mismanaged. The benefit to this, is there is room for improvement. Another form of Stack Overflow will rise, its inevitable.

Comment: EVERY YEAR, THOUSANDS of people start to learn programming.  A majority of those are going to utilize SO as a tool to "learn" (I put that in quotes, because I think too many just "want the answer").  Every year, a large set of the SAME QUESTIONS are inquired - some of which are searched for and answers found, but, alas, many are posted as NEW QUESTIONS.  And many of THOSE are either answered poorly or pointed to poorly answered duplicates, vs. being pointed to the BEST answered.  The mountain of noob questions get re-hashed EVERY YEAR, OVER AND OVER.

Comment: (continued) When asking a Q on SO, I like how SO points me to possible already-asked/answered questions related to my question.  But a noob is not even looking at those.  What can be done to encourage them to look at those over posting a noob question?

Comment: Some early questions "how do I copy a file in Python" have thousands of upvotes, despite being trivially easy to find in the documentation.  Such questions would be downvoted and closed in minutes now.  Standards have changed.

Comment: Yeah, nothing would give. Just look at Quora - a true garbage, yet doing just fine :)

Comment: Calls in any community to be "more welcoming" or "nice" to newcomers [should always be treated with suspicion, especially when they come from above](https://meaningness.com/geeks-mops-sociopaths). Quality barriers exist for a reason, and while they may be antithetical to commercial success, they are the only way to Have Nice Things(TM). Those who speak against "gatekeeping" are generally self-interested and typically keep their own set of keys (to power) *very* closely guarded.

Comment: This is just so much true! I remember when I got my first question accepted and answered - I was literally celebrating! Today, when I see some of the first posts.... Well, stop by `R` and see for yourself....

Comment: @IanKemp I looked at the meta posts announcing the new 1m rep users, and they all received lots of approval. So I'm curious about the "known rep whore" you allude to who reached 1m rep recently.

Answer (score 42):

I wrote [a blog post](https://boyl.es/post/next-month-stackoverflow-will-pass-a-catastrophic-point/) about this last year and pulled a bunch of stats with Stack Overflow's data explorer. I think it should be interesting. Running the same queries again, the picture is only getting worse.

My conclusion was yes. In almost all of the important metrics for site *quality*, Stack Overflow is getting worse. Quantity might be increasing but I just don't believe they've proven that the model scales. They grew too quickly and the site hasn't adapted to the emerging issues.

I think this is perhaps the most damning stat I found

> [image: Number of answers by year of joining]
>
> Careful with the scale here because it’s logarithmic. 54% of the class
> of 2008 have answered more than 10 questions, and 15% have answered
> more than 100. Compare that to 2019’s cohort and things are looking
> pretty dismal: 0.4% have answered more than 10 and only 0.02% have
> answered more than 100. A feat that would require the equivalent of
> posting an answer every 3 days was achieved by only 500 of the 1.7
> million new users in 2019.

Basically, what this shows is that new users are not answering questions. With millions of users registering every year, the divide between separate groups of *answerers* and *askers* grows. When answerers get disillusioned with this dynamic, their participation slows down, creating a negative feedback loop where the remaining answerers feel the strain even more. (*See edit at the end if you don't like this measurement*)

For those following along at home, it got even worse in 2020. 0.3% of the 2.2m new users answered more than 10 questions. 0.017% answered more than 100.

I know Stack Overflow is a big organization but even in that context development progress is very slow, at least on the main site. A lot of effort is dedicated to the enterprise product. Meanwhile, the flagship has remained more or less the same for *years*. We get piecemeal changes like [a tweak to the amount of rep for upvotes of questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/), or [changes to the syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter?cb=1) (this one also benefits the enterprise offering - I wonder if we'd have been lucky enough to receive it otherwise).

The Welcoming was a well-intentioned disaster that made me suspect Stack Overflow can't really identify the core issues. Again, I don't believe the model scales, and they tried to frame that as a community issue rather than an issue with their platform. New users don't know (or are not interested in learning) how to participate. Of course, everyone is responsible for what they say (though, crucially, not necessarily how they are perceived) but when you design a system that *invites frustration*, don't blame your users when they act out of frustration. Fix the system.

I get it. The help center is long and boring, and Stack Overflow is quite different from other websites. I can totally see why people wouldn't read it or would assume Stack Overflow just functions like a normal forum etc. I can't name 1 other website where you have to read so much content to know how to properly participate. I do try to remind myself of that when conducting myself here.

But in the end, for me at least, the effort required to gracefully accept an endless stream of poor quality content is just too exhausting. I've stopped participating really. The few questions I do ask, which I invest good time in and often add bounties to, get no traction at all. There really is just no value in participating here anymore.

Of course, there will always be value in the historic content to every developer but since Stack Overflow doesn't actually own that, I do wonder how long it will be before someone swipes the good content, skims off the crap, and presents it in a better package. Perhaps one where the on-site search isn't trash.

The problems they have are not trivial but they're a company with a $2B valuation and if they're worth that valuation then they should be able to solve them. I don't personally believe I know how to solve them but what I do know is that *drastic* changes are required.

For instance, we desperately need some automatic quality gate to stop the flood of awful questions. One idea I had was to require N upvoted answers before you are allowed to post your first question. If you have nothing to contribute back to other users, and will only take and take and take then I'm very sorry but we don't want you here. Yes, it would be a perfect world if every beginner could get an answer to every trivial issue they have; we tried that and it doesn't work.

Stack Overflow would probably see stifling new users from asking questions as a suicidal business move. In fact, the suicidal move is... pretty much everything they're already doing.

---

Edit:

There was some concern in the comments that this doesn't account for time spent on the site. Of course, users who have been a member of the site for longer have had longer to reach the lofty heights of 10 answers.

My presumption was that if rate-of-answering is constant (lets say 1 answer per month), then the average user would take 10 months to reach 10 answers. So for all induction years longer ago than 10 months, you would see the same percentage. The fact that you don't see that means either the rate-of-answering is ridiculously, laughably low, or the rate-of-answering is indeed declining.

So I pulled some stats on [number of answers per day since account creation](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1446852/answers-per-user-per-day-by-period-of-account-creation).

This method disproportionately harms users who have been around longer, because they are more likely to have taken hiatuses or left entirely, yet still shows they answer much more.

```
Year     Answers/user/day   1 answer every N days
2008-09  0.01833            54
2009-10  0.00912           109
2010-11  0.00404           247
2012-13  0.00184           543
2013-14  0.00108           925
2014-15  0.00085          1176
2015-16  0.00076          1315
2016-17  0.00061          1639
2017-18  0.00046          2173
2018-19  0.00044          2272
2019-20  0.00041          2439
```

Comment: Doesn't your graph show that users who have been around longer have had more time to post N answers?

Comment: That's just acknowledging it, not addressing the issue. There's far too many assumptions made in your analysis for my liking.

Comment: Isn't this just Zipf's law in effect?

Comment: Again, another assumption that is (imo) likely to be wrong. There's so many other factors to consider. Like the fact that site rules changes over time. Back in the dark ages, this site was like the wild west and just about anything was accepted, but with time and maturity things changed, often in quite dramatic ways. Comparing then to now is fraught with challenges you haven't considered.

Comment: Asking a good, intriguing question, even without having any upvoted answers, in my eyes absolutely constitutes a contribution to other users. Not just for the obvious fact that it might help someone down the line, but also for my own rather selfish motivation to answer questions here for the most part: I learned a ton of stuff by digging into problems I did not immediately know the answers to.

Comment: @shmee Sure, I agree. But the problem is that the vast majority of new users are not doing that. It would definitely be a shame to prohibit questions like that, but I think those are the kind of tough choices that need to be made. The alternative is to allow everything and wade through it manually, like we're doing now. Even though we're allowing those gems through now, they're drowned out by so much noise that they may as well not be.

Comment: Yea, this just boils down to _"Users that have been here longer have contributed more"_. Nothing new here.

Comment: While the message matches my *subjective* feeling, I can't say the presentation is *objectively* convincing. There are just too many obvious pitfalls of data analysis that aren't addressed. Is the data properly cleaned up – as in, are completely inactive and duplicate accounts filtered out? (And are they significant?) Is the model even sensible – as in, are there enough questions for all of these people to answer? Finally, does the assumption even match the implied expectation – would more answers even increase the quality of the knowledge base or just constitute duplication?

Comment: I asked a Question once. It was harder and it took longer than answering it. I don't understand this illusion that answering is giving while asking is taking. It doesn't add up at all.

Comment: @Scratte Asking a good question is much harder than answering a question. Asking a bad question takes no effort at all. So asking a good question is giving, whilst a bad question is arguably taking. And the vast majority of new questions are the bad one.

Comment: There are lots of data scientists here, so you should have known before you posted the graph that it will be critiqued by those who professionally study data.  First of all, rarely does a single data source allow for a creditable conclusion to be drawn for such a controversial topic. Secondly, this isn't a good source because `n` is just that, its `n`, not `n/years` or, `n - x * years`, which means that it would be really odd if the graph didn't look like it does, furthermore; you see quite a difference in the first two bars, and then again in the next two bars,

Comment: which IMO is due to Stack Overflow not existing before that. For the entire existence of Computer Science there was no stack overflow, then God said, "Let there be Stack Overflow!", and Stack Overflow was good (lol, okay seriously though) there is going to be an influx in experienced developers within the first few early years of Stack Overflow because they weren't able to join before a certain point, then suddenly they could.

Comment: After the first `n years` the influx of experienced developers declined, and in large part, it was only new developers who joined, and before they started answering questions, they had to start asking questions. To conclude, it doesn't make since that a developer who had 20 years of experience would wait till 2-3 years ago to make a Stack Overflow account, I can see someone not making an account all together, but not waiting it out for almost a decade, then creating an account.

Comment: @JAY-DEV "*which means that it would be really odd if the graph didn't look like it does*" I don't believe this is true based on what I already commented (and now edited in to the answer). It should not look like that if the system is working properly. Don't think I can explain it better than I already have. "*you should have known ... it will be critiqued by those who professionally study data*" I should have, but has it been? So far no one who's commented identifies as such on their profile, and their points have not been very compelling. I would expect a pro to be able to rip me to shreds.

Comment: @Michael I did data analysis in High Energy Physics (that's the LHC/CERN folks). I just don't see a point in ripping you to shreds. There are some obvious shortcommings in this analysis, and if they aren't obvious to you to the point of being alarming – then it's not much different than looking at the SO main feed with all its questions with obvious, alarming shortcommings.

Comment: @JAY-DEV I think that you're mistaken about joining. People use Stack Overflow, but don't necessarily create an account. Even if they've been working as developers for years. As an example, my account is new. I could have joined in 2009. I just didn't.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Aha, well if it helps, your original comment was certainly the most reasonable so if I had to pick a data scientist out of the lineup, it would've been you. Didn't mean any offense. I certainly agree there are shortcomings. If I had access to the full data, I'm hopeful I could do a better job. The data explorer has quite a few limitations. I think in spite of them, the results I pulled are at least indicative of (some of) Stack Overflow's problems. The company has the full data and they should be doing this analysis. Maybe they are but their actions don't convince me of it.

Comment: @Michael FWIW, no matter whether I agree with this specific analysis or not, I applaud that you tried. There's way too many anecdotes out there. Seeing some actual data, no matter the interpretation, is refreshing.

Comment: @Scratte and you feel that the majority of experienced developers back in 2009, waited until recently?

Comment: @JAY-DEV I do not know those statistics. A lot of my colleagues do not have Stack Overflow accounts (or they're not willing to share that information). Based on that, I don't think it's prudent to assume that the majority of developers *did* create an account in 2009. Also, new experts are made every day.

Comment: @JAY-DEV The answer doesn't hugely matter for Stack Overflow's continued success. Either the experts disproportionately joined towards the start of SO's life, and have since reduced their participation or left entirely, leaving the pool of experts exhausted, or they haven't but SO is not attracting them for whatever reason. In one case they are doomed by circumstances outside their control (they can't make there be more experts than there are), in the other case, they are performing badly at attracting them, with presumably no idea how to address it.

Comment: NB: bar graphs don't do well with logarithmic scales.  Why not use a regular line graph?

Comment: @gerrit Wouldn't that imply continuousness? It could be (closer to) continuous if I ran the query grouping by month or even day of creation, but when users are grouped by year, using a line might suggest a perfect linear interpolation, and that would seem disingenuous to me. I seem to remember I grouped by year because it was the best the tool could manage. I think with multiple queries and manually stitching it together it would be possible to get greater granularity. It'd be quite funny to see how Jon Skeet spiked the line on his particular day of joining.

Comment: An alternative stat that shows a similar point: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1446940 The number of new users per year who only ask questions has remained roughly steady since 2013, whilst the number of new user who have answered at least _1_ question has been steadily declining since 2013.

Comment: 2016 was the last year that we had more users join who answer questions than those that just ask.

Comment: If you restrict it to posts made within the first year of an account, its pretty clear we are in a steady state, where far more people join as askers than as answers: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1446946

Comment: So... what do we do about it? Start over? What does that even look like?

Comment: Well, the first thing we do is divide everyone up into thinkers, doers and middle men. Then in phase two... Space Goat!

Comment: @user4581301 If I tell someone to make you a thinker then they'll be a doer, and that will make me a middle man. The system works!

Comment: @KarlKnechtel A few dozen ex-users have practically re-implemented SO from scratch in their spare time in 2 years, so I suppose a fresh start is what they're hoping for. Unfortunately the name is bad and IMO it's too much of a direct clone; they haven't improved upon the source material enough. Still, it shows how few economic moats SO have. They don't own the content and the software can easily be copied. The community is their best asset and it's one that's depreciating in value. I wouldn't bet against a competitor emerging if SO don't start to improve things.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It may sound unlikely now but plenty of huge websites have risen and died: myspace, yahoo (search), megaupload, etc. Those would have seemed equally unlikely too at various times. That said, I don't think it's too late. I think with competent leadership they could still turn things around. But based on trends of the last 3-5 years, I just doubt it.

Comment: @user4581301: No, [star goat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kx-ck8gguNI&t=14m0s) (*"enormous mutant star goat"*) - at 14 min 00 secs.

Comment: Errr... Would you believe I was attempting to avoid copyright lawyers?

Comment: @Michael: It would have to be (sufficiently) qualitatively different. A clone is not enough. Who wants to start over again with 1 reputation point? Why can't reputation transfer (from different places)? A solution to the [Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) event  (it happened to Stack Overflow in 2010) and the tension with beginners needs to be found. While the current model is great for *quick* non-comprehensive answers to *new* questions, a new model could be less ego-driven and more collaborative.

Comment: [Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuCqeg4zV_o&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFJREVL6RmMnZP5U7sGYYi2)

Comment: The only solutions I know of to Eternal September are to stay small and insular and to exterminate mankind. People seem to get upset over the second option, but they should really be looking at the environmental benefits.

Comment: @Michael It would imply continuousness, but if the x-axis is time, that seems a reasonable assumption; and one can/should still clearly indicate the measurement points.  The main reason I think bar graphs aren't great for logarithmic data is because bars should connect to zero (my first thought seeing the graph was: what went from positive to negative?).

Comment: It took me at least five years after I created an account to be in the right position where I could ask and answer questions.  I'm not sure these trends are concerning. But thanks for seeking data.

Answer (score 23):

Your [latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68706754/how-to-display-a-specific-value-from-mailchimp-api-response-using-guzzle-http) was [originally](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68706754/1) tagged solely with [mailchimp-api-v3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mailchimp-api-v3.0). That tag has about 550 questions -half of which have no upvoted or accepted answer; so, it may have a limited audience.

If you were to reframe (and tag) your question so that you're asking about the common tools and patterns used to consume an API, you'd expand your pool of experts, e.g.:

> How do I get the response body from a GuzzleHttp exception?
>
> [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)[guzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guzzle)

You may even find that your question has already been asked and answered.

Comment: Thanks...guzzlehttp is a whole new thing for me, I didn't even realise it was a tag.  I will try that, but I fear the question has slipped too far over the fold to be seen now.

Comment: @Steve Editing a question bumps up to the top, usually.

Comment: It is only over the hump if you don't edit it, or do anything with it. Considering you still care about that question getting a good answer, or not, which is different from caring whether you know the answer or not. The end of the last sentence touches on one of the major problems with SO as mentioned in the first answer. If the question is no good, you need to delete it. If it has answers, try to close it, or ask those who answered to delete their answers.

Comment: You can even ask for mod help. Part of the problem rn though, is leaving questions in a purgatory state, not deleted, but unanswered, or answered by a bad answer. Another problem is comments need to be increased by 150 chars. :)

Answer (score 21):

> Is SO suffering from its own success?

The answer to that is so obvious I'm surprised it even needs to be asked. :-)

For years, SO took seriously the mantra of developing a database of high-quality answers to good questions.  Less-than-good questions were pretty seriously discouraged.  But, the forms of discouragement were often pretty harsh, could be really pretty offputting to newcomers.

A few years ago, there was a concerted effort to damp down the negativity.  This worked remarkably well: I was glad to see a drastic reduction in the amount of harsh rhetoric towards "newbie" questions.

Not surprisingly, though, this effort had the side effect of drastically increasing the number of really uninformed newbie questions: homework dumps, people trying to learn to program by typing in what they thought a C program looked like and then asking why it didn't work, etc.  I hate to admit it, but the sharp increase in poor questions shows that the former harshness towards newbies, unwelcoming though it certainly was, must have been effective in keeping the poor questions at bay.

And the problem definitely continues.  SO wouldn't be getting the continual deluge of these questions if it didn't still have a good reputation as a place to ask, and if the newbies asking these questions weren't getting answers.  So, yes, SO is certainly suffering from its own success: its success at attracting people with enough knowledge to answer questions, and its success at tamping down the negativity and becoming more welcoming to newcomers.

Personally, I have to say that I don't mind helping newbies, even with basic questions.  I was never much interested in the stated primary goal of building that database.  But I think we do need to find new, not-unfriendly ways of discouraging (or at least declining to encourage) those classes of questions which we decide we don't want.

Comment: Thank you for acknowledging that just letting everyone be rude is not the answer. I'm sick of people trying to make "welcoming" into a swear word.

Comment: @IMSoP yet examples of rude behavior were rare and sparse. Rudeness is after all in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: The most common examples of rudeness i ran into were people attacking others for not being welcoming enough.

Comment: @IMSoP to SO curators, it is a swear word.  Deadbeats who got their questions downvoted/closed/deleted resorted to 'Contact us' emails, blogs and other social media to spread the 'hostile, toxic' mantra, covering up their lack of substantial evidence with 'feelings' and claims of misogyny, racial and anti-LGBTQ+ bias.  SO believed what they read on the internet and opened fire on curators from the 'Welcome Tank':(

Answer (score 18):

We see more questions for the following reasons:

- **The early days were frontloaded with experts.** It is expected that some users will have more enthusiasm in participating when they first join. In the early days this would have contributed to an infusion of enthusiasm from experts into the system, but now that these experts have all joined already, this phenomenon now means there is more enthusiasm from question asking novice programmers.
- **[SJW](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/SJW#Noun) decisions Stack Overflow has made** with [pronoun usage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes) and the [removal of Monica](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336526/stack-overflow-is-doing-me-ongoing-harm-its-time-to-fix-it)[[2]](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/stack-overflow-inc-sinat-chinam-and-the-goat-for-azazel/5197#5197) have led to some users to [stop lending their time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper) to moderation activities, and some users even stopped answering questions.
- **English as a second language.** Not a bad thing, but I feel like there are more people who speak English as a second language and are not able to express themselves as well. This bullet point doesn't have anything to do with the number of questions asked, but it does affect question quality, so I thought I would point it out alongside everything else.
- **People with no desire to go into a programming related field**. There are more people taking programming courses in junior high and high school and there are more people who try to use a little bit of programming in other career fields too. These people ask more questions than they give answers for.
- **Frayed relationships**. Stack Overflow did attack us maintainers for not being friendly enough, causing some people to second guess why they were helping a for-profit entity. In the early days there was a much healthier relationship between SO and those that contribute. SO hasn't done much in the last few years that would rally up excitement among those that contribute (although lately they have been doing a good job improving communication with the community, so this could improve in the near future if positive actions follow).
- **When SO first started there were many more good questions that needed to be asked** about features in various languages/tools. Those have, for the most part, been answered for all but the newest languages/tool features.
- **The compounding affect.** Users who remember how SO used to be become frustrated and leave, leaving fewer people to maintain things. This makes the problem worse and the effect compounds.

Most of the above bullet points are out of SO's control. They can try and make amends for decisions they made as a company, although, from what I can tell, [the impact of their decisions has been small](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1421108/answered-unanswered-year-over-year#graph).

This doesn't mean that there are no good solutions. There are plenty of things SO is able to do to make this place better unrelated to the above bullet points. The close system needs to be revamped. A separate space within SO or on a separate Stack Exchange could be created for help desk style questions. And I'm sure we could come up with a long list of solutions if we tried, (and if someone at SO actually lends some dev resources to fixing the problem, sigh...).

— I think many of the bulleted items are good problems. I'm just trying to layout what is going on.

Comment: "Compounding affect" is probably a typo, but it seems oddly suitable.

Comment: "SJW decisions Stack Overflow has made with pronoun usage and removing certain moderators have led to some users to stop lending their time to moderating activities, and some users have even stopped answering questions."

Dude you're projecting yourself.

Comment: When I mentioned moderators being removed, I was mostly referring to Monica (I couldn't remember her name at the time). The post that announced the new pronoun usage was the most downvoted answer on here. It's since been removed, but I recall there were many people stating that they were going to stop their moderation activities as a result, and there was some discussion if it was best to just stop helping out in review queues or to stop review queues + answering questions. Here is a list of just the moderators who resigned https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced

Comment: That string of bad decisions and strange choices on SE's behalf definitely had a lot of fallout, and an undeniable lasting impact on regulars who were around at the time. Whether that has impacted curation or expert contributions in any meaningful way is a little less obvious, but that period definitely had consequences.

Comment: @FarhoodET your comment reads like you didn't bother to check the link under words "stop lending their time" in this post. Possibly you also aren't aware of posts in [meta-tag:moderator-resignation] tag over here?

Comment: I edited my post to include those links after Farhood's comment, to better explain things for all those who weren't around at the time that stuff was going on.

Comment: I imagine that what Farhood objects (or at least what I object to), is using the term "SJW". This helps to conflate many different issues under the same derogatory term. There are many of us that are completely in favour of making the site more inclusive, and adapting/changing language when appropriate. And yet we were deeply disappointed in the way things transpired regarding Monica, or the firing of certain employees. What you seem to be "projecting" is having a problem with what you describe as "SJW", and by using that term you detract from an otherwise reasonable answer.

Comment: @FarhoodET No, he isn't. I'm one of those who stopped contributing entirely as a direct result of the SJW agenda. And I'm certainly not the only one, as the effects are [demonstrable](https://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/how_sjws_affected_stack_overflow.shtml).

Comment: @demonstrable Stackoverflow implemented a terrible policy even more terribly which led to many leaving the site. But using "SJW" unironically is never a good sign either.

Answer (score 13):

> Is SO suffering from its own success?

Yes.

Maybe they feel that they're too big to fail or that they no longer need the "community" anymore.

> Are there any plans to address this issue?

From what we used to get told, there are/were lots of plans. But no actual action and as the old saying goes "actions speak louder than words".

If I had to guess, quite a few of the long-time contributers just left or became spectators, because, well, they've fallen for the empty words one too many times and y'know, [fool me once](https://knowyourphrase.com/fool-me-once).

I know several high rep users that deleted their accounts and where I normally spend time, in [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), the old guard that I used to see around have disappeared.

It's quite clear that's SO's vision and the "communities" vision is quite different these days and has been so for some time now.

We've been repeatedly told:

> *We messed up with our communications and release plan on this one.*

or

> *We'll do better to communicate our plans in the future.*

but repeatedly, SO has sprung changes upon us without any discussion. Empty promises and lack of proper action hasn't helped either.

I took a step back from SO ~March 2020 and I only recently just started visiting it again (~1 week) just in time to [see this mess](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive).

Good old SO, never fails to disppoint.

**Reading Material**

- [What's up with the breakdown in communication between Stack Overflow and the community?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387599/whats-up-with-the-breakdown-in-communication-between-stack-overflow-and-the-com)
- [SE seems pretty set in their path to change the sites as we know them and the testimony of former employees are proof of that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342466/se-seems-pretty-set-in-their-path-to-change-the-sites-as-we-know-them-and-the-te)
- [Meta: Can we influence and change policy or is our role reduced to exegesis of company commandments and acclamation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335289/meta-can-we-influence-and-change-policy-or-is-our-role-reduced-to-exegesis-of-c)
- [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper)

Comment: Due to this mess from Sep '19 on I too reduced my activities on SE since lately: [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/273829). And such doesn't make me happier or more motivated since: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410687/is-so-suffering-from-its-own-success#comment860009_410687.

Answer (score 0):

###### *"After writing three comments I decided to answer this because I feel I have valid point to share."*

### Take it w/ a Grain of Salt

---

@Micheal [answered this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410715/), (his answer is currently above this answer), and he shared a graph. Where I don't agree with his conclusion that he drew from the graph, I commend him on offering a creditable source of data, that further helps us to draw a more meaningful conclusion, because, without some source of data, it's all just opinion, hearsay, and not none of it is really that valuable right? So IMO most of what is read here should be taken with a grain of salt, unless it is backed by some sort of evidence, which doesn't necessarily make it true, or false, but it can be more likely to be true, or more likely to be false, if that makes sense.

### What's the Deal with Contemporary Stack Overflow?

---

Some people say that ***Stack Overflow*** is suffering, as can be seen in the title of this question *["Is SO suffering from its own success?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410687/is-so-suffering-from-its-own-success?cb=1#410715)*. Some argue that SO is not suffering, but is doing well, especial in terms of dollar signs **$$$**. Some think Stack Overflow is worse off, and some of the new users feel Stack Overflow has become more friendly. I have heard all the opinions, and one thing for sure can be concluded:

##### "Stack Overflow has changed, and is not the same thing as it was 10+ years ago."

Personally, I don't think it is suffering necessarily, and I don't think it is not suffering. If you write in a language like ANSI C, it might appear a little more worse off than if you write something like [Rust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_%28programming_language%29), [TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_%28programming_language%29), or [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29), because those languages are new, with new young users and the topics are a bit more vibrant, whereas C, especially to a new user, might seem like a tag that has lots of *"mean"* old users answering its questions a place with mean people, however, C is one of the best tags to be involved in, because of the amount of experience that C developers, who post under the C tag, have.

There is a difference between being mean, and being direct. Lots of new users confuse the two, and in all honesty, I used to. Today, I realize that I can talk to experienced computer scientists, data scientists, senior software engineers, lead techs, applications developers, frontend, backend, full-stack, etc... etc.. etc... And I am damn lucky to have such a resource. There is a lack of application from some people, and often times when corrected on semantics, or even their basic English, they respond like a rabid dog trapped in a corner; it's very primitive behavior for such a contemporary and complex subject.

The reason it has changed as such is that every CS student that is in high school, and/or college, learns about Stack Overflow around the same time that they write their first "Hello, World!" program (in whatever language). Some of them become experienced developers, and some of them don't, but the ones that do become experienced professionals are going to be far and far in between, where the inexperienced is going to be a dime a dozen.

Looking at it this way, it is easy to see how Stack Overflow has changed. SO used to be full of experience every day you looked, and that is just not the case any more. This equates to far more edits, and reviews being needed, and fewer people to do them. IMO, Stack Overflow was not created for its current user base, and it is attempting to adjust. Stack Overflow needs a makeover, and it is likely that another computer science-based Q&A style platform will launch, and have a good bit of success in the future, as there are plenty of visitors for a couple of CS Q&A platforms.

This is my opinion, but I feel that it is pretty valid.

Comment: I know I have got to have some spelling, and grammatical mistakes. I got to go to work for 3 hours, and will edit when I get home.

Comment: No the people have changed, they use the word "feelings" a whole lot more for example. I direct your attention to the very last sentence of your own answer here. Stack Overflow has NOT changed, it is still pretty much designed for the IT person of a decade+ ago. Neutral, all business, no nonsense. That makes it a difficult pill to swallow for people who let emotions dictate their thinking. Because then neutrality becomes coldness or even anger, downvotes and close votes become personal attacks. Stack Overflow becomes... toxic. In their eyes, at least. Maybe SO is becoming a relic, who knows.

Comment: @Gimby Well said Gimby. Through my answer I found myself trying to make sense of this question, which seems to be more philosophical in nature than I had expected it to be. I was trying to say something along the same lines as your comment, and any statements that implemented a change in Stack Overflow were intended to implement that the group of people that make up the entire Stack Overflow Community has significantly changed.

Comment: Re *"currently above this answer"*: That may depend on the selected view ("Active", "Oldest", or "Votes")

Comment: "*and the topics are a bit more vibrant*" as somebody looking at the TS tag...not really. Plenty of questions are *extremely* basic stuff of the form "Compiler tells me I cannot assign a string to a number. How do I fix it?" where the response is largely based on "Read the error message". A *very large* portion of the questions stem from people just not even being aware how TS works at the most basic levels - it takes TS code -> compiles it to JS code. It also checks if the TS code *seems* correct at the time of compilation.

Comment: "*Stack Overflow was not created for its current user base*" 100% "*and it is attempting to adjust*" Maybe they are but it *feels* like they're not because the rate of change is just so slow. Pair that with the fact that practically every change SO make nowadays is met with some community backlash (the profile changes, for example), I have very little faith that they'll be able to properly plan for the substantial changes which are required, and deliver them in a timely manner. "*Stack Overflow needs a makeover*" It needs much more than that. Some core functionality needs overhauling.

Comment: @VLAZ By, more vibrant, I just meant less explored, less answered, and more to ask about. They are no doubt better tags for someone that is hungry for rep, however, as languages go, I myself am 34 (not old, not young. I am sort of in the middle) I prefer the older languages, I actually really like writing CLI's in BASH & ANSI-C.

Comment: @Micheal, I think Gimby makes a good point that S.O. is the same as always, kind of dry and neutral, and it seems like surprisingly, even after more than a decade, people have been unable to swallow that pill. Neutrality is absolutely  necessary for an accurate site that promotes correctness, and I think a lot of people who are the same generation as me ("millennials") as I am, like to be right in a way that's absolute, and that sort of attitude isn't good for Computer Science in general.

Answer (score -5):

> Pretty much every other SE community I am in has an empty review queue, but in the case of SO, **it looks like it will never be cleared**.

Correct.

---

> I suspect that the overall quality of SO questions and answers is suffering due to its own success.

You really want to open up this can of dead horses for another beating?

[Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow)

[Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late)

---

> Are there any plans to address this issue?

**Review queue**

Sure, get more people to volunteer in the clusterf*** known as the review queue. Are you helping to solve the issue? You're above 500 rep you know... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406169/2191572

**Question quality**

Please refer to "can of dead horses" sentiment.

Comment: 1: that is the problem.  2: not intentionally, but if that is the result, fine 3: Yes 4: Something needs to be done or it is a downward spiral

Comment: Although I kind of agree with the general premise of this answer, I can never upvote an answer which is this crass. There is absolute no need to convey the message you are trying to convey with this kind of tone.

Comment: IMO, this isn't just a topic thats going to go away, and why would we want it too. The more it is discussed, the better off Stack Overflow is. Stack Overflow is community ran, and the community really decides if S.O. is a good, or a bad resource. Those who are more involved than others will talk about it, and like I said they should. It helps everyone be more grounded in knowledge about what Stack Overflow is, and what's good about it, and what it lacks. Its important, especially if you care about the languages you write, as S.O. probably has a major effect on them.

Answer (score -16):

To some extent the sheer number of questions are the problem. This could trivially be addressed by splitting it by language (C#, T-SQL, Python, etc.). From the point of view of someone working with a given tech stack, everything outside that stack is pollution. No doubt some people will violently disagree and inform me that this is what tags are for, but if they were right there wouldn't be a problem for you to have noticed.

Why don't people care about reputation any more? Why so many first posts?

Because participation is likely to result in a slap in the face.

Consider a question of mine which as it happens has just been closed without so much as an advisory comment. It's a beginner question because I am new to the topic of [InfluxDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InfluxDB). If I *knew* what I didn't know I wouldn't waste my time with Stack Overflow, I'd just search the Influx documentation.

Now, it turned out that the problem was just permissions due to a misunderstanding of how to assign permissions when creating a token. So I wrote an answer explaining why the problem was hidden (the error whizzes offscreen amid masses of assembly load messages) and explaining how to correctly assign permissions when creating a token.

The question and answer are *useful* to a novice. But the question has been closed anyway. I shouldn't feel hurt; I'm used to this kind of treatment. But rejection is tough irrespective of whether it's justified and it's the reason I tend to avoid contributing to Stack Overflow.

At this point someone will start to explain rules and how vital it is to enforce them, but the rest of the Internet translates this to "because f**k you", often in these words when out of reach of those who might take exception.

Irrespective of whether the rules are justified, they offend people and repel them. You might think "good riddance to bad rubbish, we are superior because [reasons]". That's the position the Spartans took, with some justification. The only war they ever lost was the war of attrition that you have noticed.

The ideas behind this line of thought (crappy questions are harmless because vote ranking; curation is a waste of time because search engines already do it better, cross-referenced duplicates are *useful* because expressing the question in different ways improves the chance of finding it) are heresy of the foulest stripe. They challenge fundamental precepts and call into question time-honoured values and assumptions. If you actually read this far, well done.

Comment: Yes, it is probably better to write a blog post instead.

Comment: Questions should not be closed because they are "too simple" or the answer can be found elsewhere. If that's actually what happened, it was an incorrect closure; plain and simple. Please post a Meta question or raise a moderator flag to get it re-opened.

Comment: There's no reason to "write a blog post instead". Stack Overflow is explicitly designed to host self-answered questions containing bite-sized information (in a Q&A format!) that would be useful to programmers of all levels. *This* should be the place where you write that blog post, except that you should pretend that you're on Jeopardy, and write it in the form of a question and answer. @PeterMortensen

Comment: The rules exist because certain types of content just should not exist on this platform. The obvious examples are spam and anything not related to programming. The less obvious examples are questions that ask for recommendations (because they become targets for spam), questions that are too broad for our Q&A format, questions that contain insufficient information to be answered (because they lead to random guesses being posted, instead of objective, verifiable answers), etc. These, garnered from years of experience, are enshrined as the close reasons. Vote ranking serves a different purpose.

Comment: @CodyGray [the rule exist because...] Sure, and I'm pleased to see this position taken by a moderator. I couldn't count the number of questions I've seen close because they were "too vague" that had been given a concrete usable answer.  Those who closed them demonstrated two failures of understanding - not only did they judge the question incorrectly, they failed to recognise their own limitations. On more than one occasion I have seen a question closed as too vague _after_ it was successfully answered. In my opinion that's absurd.

Comment: @Cody Gray: That is the theory. But most users don't understand or misunderstand the concept of self-answered questions. Or suffer from rep-envy. The Stack Overflow software ought to make it much more self-evident that it is perfectly acceptable, but such a change will never happen.

Comment: _"On more than one occasion I have seen a question closed as too vague after it was successfully answered. In my opinion that's absurd."_ Following the same logic, if you asked a question about cooking and you received an answer (and a helpful one, let's say), then we shouldn't close the question, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if by "too vague", you mean "too broad" or "unclear". If it's the former, then the question should be closed (in most cases) even if it received an answer. If it's the latter, and the question received an answer that got accepted, I'd say the best course of action is to edit the post to make it clear (perhaps the answerer should do so).

Comment: @41686d6564 Isn't the purpose of asking the question to get the answer though? I've often wondered why an asker cares if the question gets closed/etc if they actually get an answer, seems the site worked if that happened. What's their incentive to clarify?

Comment: Your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68720218/208273) was closed because it seemed to ask multiple questions.  The title was "Understanding InfluxDb2 introductory sample" and there were three bullet points with a question attached to each of them. It was not clear that it was _just_ about the failure to insert data into the bucket. Titles should summarize the problem to be addressed—I've now edited the title to clarify that it is specifically about the failure to write data and voted to reopen your question.

Comment: Your question was closed because it is not a *question*. It's a bulleted list of multiple questions.  SO is not a *here's my list of questions asking for an explanation of things*. SO is for single specific questions, and that's not what you posted. If you had clearly specified what you were asking rather than making it so broad in scope and using a list of multiple questions, it probably wouldn't have been closed. Your misdirection by making this about *reputation* rather than *lack of clarity by the poster* isn't really appropriate. After @RyanM's edit, I've also voted to reopen.

Comment: @DanChase There are several things that could be considered an incentive but most new askers don't know about them anyway, and that's why I said perhaps the _answerer_ should make the clarifying edit (I think the incentive is obvious here). As for the asker, an example of an incentive is making sure the question is well-received; which leads to a) avoiding question-bans (i.e., maintaining the ability to post more questions) and b) gaining more rep that they can use for starting bounties on their other questions (among other benefits).

Comment: I am honestly unsure what this answer is intended to achieve, given the massive tonal difference of its final paragraph. Is it intended to be a massive /s? If so, well done!

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by the message of this answer. On the one hand, it starts by complaining that a Q&A got closed without comments indicating why it did not fit the rules. On the other hand, it uses rather... unwelcoming language to describe how such comments are received, perceived and even intended, which suggests one should not leave such comments. Which is it? Is it both?

Comment: For me personally, if you are "new to a topic" then [so] shouldn't be your first port of call. Instead, you should be going to official sources of documentation, looking through tutorials, books even (I know what's a book, right?). Then when you have a "specific problem" based on that knowledge you've garnered, ask on [so].

Comment: _"cross-referenced duplicates are useful because expressing the question in different ways improves the chance of finding it"_ is hardly "heresy", that's one of the things https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/ says. The problem is that while the 2nd, 3rd, 5th, 10th versions _might_ be useful signposts, if they do indeed add searchable terms, is the 10,000th on e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/14220321?

Comment: @DanChase "if they actually get an answer, seems the site worked if that happened." Not really. The site is meant to gather a knowledge base of high quality questions and answers. If there is an unclear question with a lucky guess of an answer, that does not mean "the site worked". The site works when *more than two people (the asker and the answerer)* benefit from the Q & A pair.

Comment: Upvoted. He's not saying anything wrong.

Comment: @user692942 Basic education steps, really. Going to Stack Overflow when you haven't properly informed yourself first is like going into a library for a book without having learned how to read first and then asking the people around you "what are these symbols on the paper?" - and then getting mad when people tell you that maybe you should learn how to read to understand what a book says. It is not about people not wanting to help you... they can't help you. Ignorance is not bliss, it is self-sabotage.

Comment: @Gimby couldn't agree more.

Comment: @CarloWood The problem is, quote "*It's a beginner question because I am new to the topic of InfluxDB. If I knew what I didn't know I wouldn't waste my time with Stack Overflow, I'd just search the Influx documentation.*". No, if they don't know a topic then [so] isn't the place to come to. They should first be going to the official documentation, tutorials, forums, books (yes books!) etc, their approach is the wrong way round.

Comment: @CodyGray You're right in your first responses, and not everybody has the experience that Peter Wone did, but the fact that his answer has been downoted to -18 or so proves pretty conclusively that he's spot-on when he "challenges fundamental precepts and calls into question time-honoured values and assumptions".

Comment: Just because someone managed to guess correctly in a number of cases doesn't mean those cases didn't "contain insufficient information to be answered". with enough experience, one can accurately guess in many cases what is wrong, but the question should still be clarified first so that it can be properly handled, whether that be through dupe closure or receiving an answer.

Comment: @GameDungeon can you link it so we can see it for ourselves, might be able to suggest how you could improve the answer?

Comment: @SteveSummit a -18 DV count proves someone is right? You must have read something backwards, as this means that the community is happy with the rules, and they like filtering out simple questions that shouldn't be asked. Did we not look at how full the review queues are in the Original Question? Stack Overflow should not be treated as a platform where people come to learn fundamental issues, otherwise, it loses all the value it has for experienced programmers, and it is only because it attracts the best programmers worldwide that it is as valuable as it is.

Comment: I don't expect anyone who is relatively new at programming to understand this. I didn't understand it when I first joined in 2017, but after writing code for rigorously 7+ years, (I know the math doesn't add up, I wrote code before I was a s.o. member), its become crystal clear. Learning developers expect that the platform should cater to them, as I already stated, I use to feel that way too, and I regret it, as it was totally selfish and unjustified of me.

Answer (score -23):

I think a financial incentive could go a long way. Building on the collective idea that was recently launched, I think SO could create a way for SMEs with a certain tool/language to have paid help opportunities. People seeking answers could spend real cash.

Take it a step further, maybe rep could be something like airline miles where they do have a real world value and you can buy your way in and redeem to help.

Just ideas, don't roast me into oblivion...

Comment: This is meta. Everyone is subject to gratuitous amounts of roasting. No rep loss = no butt-hurt.

Comment: "maybe rep could […] have a real world value" Ugh, please no. There is enough rep farming already...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - would like to hear your ideas about incentivizing better answer creation.

Comment: @serraosays Any specific reason, or did you just mean to disagree?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - My experience with this community is tons of complaining and shooting down of ideas, which is fine I guess. Your comment fits into the mold so I'm asking if you have a creative approach to getting more folks to contribute their time.

Comment: Adding money into the equation would just make it worse, IMHO. It would just lead to SMEs witholding answers/help in exchange for cash (which is exactly the platform SE/SO was built against) and/or a lot more low-quality posts because who doesn't want to get paid (we already have this problem with just imaginary rep points). I suggest searching for "paid help" over at meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @GinoMempin counter with ideas instead of criticism.

Comment: Here's an idea: Moderation should be the job of full time staff, not volunteers or paid strangers. They are running a business but not really. On the one hand, it's cool that you can mod here, on the other hand that really is a job. Shouldn't at least someone on the SO side be tasked with cleaning up their own platform?

Comment: @serraosays "*counter with ideas instead of criticism*"  That is just a poor way to deflect valid criticism.

Comment: @serraosays "Your comment fits into the mold so I'm asking if you have a creative approach to getting more folks to contribute their time." I don't. And I don't think it should be the goal. We need less trash, not more people to sift through it. We need to accept that some things are trash, not invest endless effort to explain and appease at that trash...